# "Deviates from the original intent"?

Tags: discussion, editing

I suggested [this edit](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/601) yesterday: the question is about using Mercurial with emacs, I suggest to remove the [git](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/git) tag. As far as I could tell, it was a trivial edit that someone would have suggested sooner or later, and I didn't expect any problem at the review.

However, it was rejected, by 2 votes out of 3. And it is not even because it would be too trivial, rather, both rejecters agreed that this edit "deviates from the original intent" of the question. It is also the first edit these two reviewers ever reject, so I cannot accuse them of routinely rejecting edits.

So... I'm really confused now: is there something obvious that I am missing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I wasn't one of those who reviewed, but I think I'd have rejected as
well.

The question is about both git and mercurial. That's all, really.

The git part is just tangentially mentioned, which is why your reviews were somewaht divided, but those users considered that removing the tag didn't really help.
Instead of removing the git tag I'd have added the mercurial tag.

Comment: So that implies that it is ok to use tags to mark "tangential relations", or hard relations? If tangential relations are enough, should we tag all generic `{version-control}` questions with `{git}`, `{hg}`, `{svn}`, `{bzr}`... ?

Comment: @T.Verron All that implies is that the reviewers didn't see fit to remove a tag that was explicitly referred to in the question. If you want to remove that tag, edit the question as well.

Comment: "Ultimately, the problem is in the question, for tangetially asking an entirely new question." I disagree with that. Emacs does include a version-control system that works consistently with most VCSs. This is what the OP was using, and in this workflow, asking about git or hg is not two different questions. But a magit answer would definitely be off-topic. (For example if you replace `git` with `svn` in the question, is it better? I surely hope not!)

Comment: @T.Verron No problem, I removed that last sentence. I don't know how much HG's external interface has in common with git.

Comment: @T.Verron Still, your point in the first comment is a bit dramatic. Git was explicitly mentioned in the question. svn and bzr weren't.

Comment: For the 1st comment: to be honest I have no idea either. `:)` For the 2nd: the point is that this question is about `vc-` (generic VCS support), not particularly about git. The OP chose to mention primarily hg (and not create a tag for it), and git (as I see it, only as an example to point out that his problem is not specific to one VCS). He chose to add the git tag for some reason (maybe I should have asked him that first), but this tag mad the question look specific to git. See for example the page title "git - Insert and strip..."! ...

Comment: ... Now I understand your point that git *is* specifically mentionned and thus deserves that tag. That's why I ask if it would be better if svn was mentioned instead of git? It would make no difference to the question, but now the tag wouldn't exist, making it less tempting to add. But intrinsically, since it doesn't make a difference to the question, it shouldn't make a difference to the tagging... Hence, why the `git` tag? (Btw, thanks, at least I got rid of the assumption that it should have been trivially accepted `:)` )

Comment: To be more constructive: would you consider creating a hg tag for this question a reasonable way out of the problem? --- Edit: Ah, never mind, I see that you have just done that. But git is still the first tag, so the titlepage will not change. `:(`

Comment: Yes, as you noticed, I do support the correct thing here is to create a tag for mercurial (and yes, I'd create one for svn  and whatnot if they had been explicitly invoked). Probably, the OP didn't create one because new users can't create tags. Your point about the title page is valid, but it's a consequence of how SE works (it just chooses the most popular tag to place on the front page). The only way around that would be to invite the OP to focus the question on HG, or just let it go. :-)

Comment: Since the question got an answer (about hg) by now, I guess it is harmless to let it go, indeed.